# Find simple position of regexp match in string in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I am trying to find the first position of regexp in the string (the exact position id) to be able to delete it, but I can't find such a solution in PostgreSQL.

My query eats separators and combines strings and tries to cut only values between separators. For example, when I have a string value in a column such as:

```
57080*570801*157080*5708011
670811*67081*670810*670815
```

I tried to use:

```
UPDATE tab 
set str = (REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '^57080*', '')
WHERE myColumn=159880;
```

or

```
UPDATE tab 
set str = (REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '*57080*', '')
WHERE myColumn=159880;
```

or

```
UPDATE tab 
set str = (REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '*57080$', '')
WHERE myColumn=159880;
```

However, this doesn't help me because after using
 `(REGEXP_REPLACE (str, '* 57080 *', '')` I have a stuck id (e.g. `57080570801`). I need to find my regexp position somehow to be able to cut only the id. After that I can always use `REPLACE (string , '**', '*')` which will cut out double characters or

```
SET str = CASE
WHEN str LIKE '*%' THEN RIGHT (str, LENGTH (str) -1)
WHEN str LIKE '% *' THEN LEFT (str, LENGTH (str) -1)
```

will cut the start / end characters (`*`). Does anyone have any idea how to easily find positions of such a regexp.

Comment: Can you be clearer , so you have this `57080*570801*157080*5708011` and what do you want as output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the “beginning of word” and “end of word” markers:

```
regexp_replace(str, '\m12345\M', '')
```